# Неправильное отображение соц. кнопок

Tags: javascript, facebook

Нужен блок социальных кнопок для сайта, все кнопки собрал, засунул в общий див с ориентацией. Но кнопка facebook бычит, и не влезает в строку. (Она переходит на строку ниже или выше). Подскажите как её правильно уместить?

```
`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Frookami.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`
```

Comment: @HappyCougar, Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ на свой вопрос, отметьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может попробовать засунть в отдельный див с

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: да, помогло display:inline; на каждый див